# Is pd.get_dummies one-hot encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

[Given](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224051/99338) the difference between one-hot encoding and dummy coding, is the `pandas.get_dummies` method one-hot encoding when using default parameters (i.e. `drop_first=False`)?

If so, does it make sense that I remove the intercept from the logistic regression model? Here is an example:

```
# I assume I have already my dataset in a DataFrame X and the true labels in y
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = pd.get_dummies(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .80)

clf = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Dummies are any variables that are either one or zero for each observation.  `pd.get_dummies` when applied to a column of categories where we have **one** category per observation will produce a new column (variable) for each unique categorical value.  It will place a one in the column corresponding to the categorical value present for that observation.  This is equivalent to one hot encoding.

One-hot encoding is characterized by having only one one per set of categorical values per observation.

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(list('AABBCCABCDDEE'))

s

0     A
1     A
2     B
3     B
4     C
5     C
6     A
7     B
8     C
9     D
10    D
11    E
12    E
dtype: object
```

`pd.get_dummies` will produce one-hot encoding.  And yes! it is absolutely appropriate to not fit the intercept.

```
pd.get_dummies(s)

    A  B  C  D  E
0   1  0  0  0  0
1   1  0  0  0  0
2   0  1  0  0  0
3   0  1  0  0  0
4   0  0  1  0  0
5   0  0  1  0  0
6   1  0  0  0  0
7   0  1  0  0  0
8   0  0  1  0  0
9   0  0  0  1  0
10  0  0  0  1  0
11  0  0  0  0  1
12  0  0  0  0  1
```

However, if you had `s` include different data and used `pd.Series.str.get_dummies`

```
s = pd.Series('A|B,A,B,B,C|D,D|B,A,B,C,A|D'.split(','))

s

0    A|B
1      A
2      B
3      B
4    C|D
5    D|B
6      A
7      B
8      C
9    A|D
dtype: object
```

Then `get_dummies` produces dummy variables that are not one-hot encoded and you could theoretically leave the intercept.

```
s.str.get_dummies()

   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  1  1
5  0  1  0  1
6  1  0  0  0
7  0  1  0  0
8  0  0  1  0
9  1  0  0  1
```

Comment: OK! That makes absolutely sense. My case reflects the former example, having *one and only one* category per observation (in this case, a country name). But, as I can see, the pandas method could not lead to a one-of-K encoding all the time. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Where did we mention, separator is '|'??

Comment: It’s the default in str.get_dummies

Answer (score 5):

**First question**: yes, `pd.get_dummies()` is one-hot encoding in its default state; see example below, from [pd.get_dummies docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))
pd.get_dummies(s, drop_first=False)
```

**Second question**: [edited now that OP includes code example] yes, if you are one-hot encoding the inputs to a logistic regression model, it is appropriate to skip the intercept.